# Using JS IPFS in the Browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, ipfs

I am developing a digital wallet and I am using ipfs inside a web extension, but I have the following errors:

[image]

this is my code:

```
const node = await Ipfs.create()
const results = await node.add('hello manlio')
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results)
```

How to solve these errors ? thanks

I tried the following examples on ipfs: https://github.com/ipfs-examples/js-ipfs-examples

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few potential issues that could cause errors in this code:

Make sure that the IPFS library is correctly imported and available in your code. You can do this by adding the following line at the top of your code:
import Ipfs from 'ipfs';

Make sure, also, that the element with the ID 'demo' exists in the HTML document. If it does not exist, the following line of code will throw an error:
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results) .

If you are running this code in a web browser, you may need to handle any potential CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) errors. You can do this by serving your HTML file from a local web server, or by using a CORS proxy.

Comment: I don't see how any of those suggestions could related to the error message that the OP posted a picture of.